# How do I change the color of all the elements (onHover) in a <td> even though some are wrapped in <span>?

Tags: html, css

The implementation is here: http://jsfiddle.net/chp8y/1/

If you hover over the first box, #1, you will see the 'Add Client' change color but the #1 won't. How do I achieve that without using JS ?

If you do a `.sit-in-the-corner:hover` it will only work when you hover over the 1. But that's not what I want.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't it a case of changing the last rule to:

```
table td:hover, table td:hover span {
      color: #aa5650;
}
```

Comment: One quick question...what about if the :hover for the table did something else like changed the border. For instance, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3pVG/   I don't want the 1 to have a border - just change the color. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Spin out an additional rule - one rule for styles applied to both elements and another rule for styles applied to just one element.  http://jsfiddle.net/amelvin/778n2/

Comment: Thanks. Nice and elegant. Love it.

Answer (score 3):

THe style for the class has higher precedence than the style for the tag, so it will override it.

You can add a style that removes the specific setting for the span when the cell is hovered:

```
table td:hover .sit-in-the-corner {
  color: inherit;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chp8y/5/

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the #s with anchor tags. Drop the color attribute from the .sit-in-the-corner and add that attribute to the anchors. Like this:

HTML:

```
<span class="sit-in-the-corner"><a class="tile-number">1</a></span>
```

CSS:

```
.sit-in-the-corner {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: -85px;
}

.tile-number {
    color: #556655;
}
```